# .htaccess file. Too many redirects to subdomain when using SSL cert and cloudflare?

Tags: .htaccess

My website is using cloudflare with an SSL cert. My main domain is working correctly with SSL.

I'm trying to do the same for a subdomain. The padlock shows as it should, but errors showing too many redirects?

I have placed the .htaccess file in the directory of the subdomain path with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried many alterations but cant fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of checking for the port, have you tried checking `%{HTTPS}` for `off`?

Comment: oh yes, tried that but no luck